# Media Query works in the first screen but doesn't work in the next

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on making my website responsive. It has been designed in a 14inch laptop which has a screen size of around 1100px. To make it responsive I have started from small screens:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 399px)
```

Now when I move onto the next media query, no code actually works(but it works below 400px).

These are the media query I am planning to work on:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 767px)
@media only screen and  (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)
@media only screen and  (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)
@media only screen and  (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1399px)
```

Is there anything wrong with writing those statements? Or is the order wrong?

Comment: Personally, I would only worry about mobile, tablet (>786) and desktop (>960). Give your content container max-width of 1920 and that's usually a good starting point for me.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comment. I am actually using 100vw for width and 100vh for height as the background is a full-screen slider. Moreover, it's a no scroll website.

Comment: Even in that case, you can have your queries like for mobile, tablet and desktop. One question I would ask is what if the screen size is bigger than 1399? What would happen then?

Comment: Lol actually I have some more media queries already setup. I havent pasted those here. I'm planning to make it responsive till 1900px. This is because I haven't used any framework and everything falls apart in larger screens. As I mentioned in the OP that my laptop is around 1100 px, everything seems to be okay in that but my brother's monitor is around 1800 px and everything gets ruined.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox have developer tools which allow for development for different screens and there are some useful extensions available too. Like I said before, I would keep it to 3 queries for: mobile, tablet and desktop. Also, consider using responsive metrics such as em or rem for sizes of elements.

Comment: Noted. Thanks. But can you please tell me if there's anything wrong with those media queries? Why doesn't the codes work? Any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199210/discussion-between-bywaleed-and-zak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 767px) {

  .content {
    right: 0px !important;
  }


}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1399px) {}



@media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) and (max-width: 1599px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) and (max-width: 1799px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1800px) and (max-width: 1999px) {
  /*.content {
    position: absolute;
    right: 310px;
    top: 234px;
    width: 880px;
}

.background-overlay {
    height: 600px;
}
#about h1{
    font-size: 80px;
}
.content .aboutUs {
    padding: 60px 45px 0px 45px;
}
.content .aboutUs div {
    margin-top: 35px;
    height: 382px;
}
.content .aboutUs p {
    margin-right: 32px;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-weight:400;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    color: #777;
}

}
*/


}
```

An improvements I suggest is that you have 3 media queries like so:

(max-width: 640px)

(min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 800px)

(min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1024px)

(min-width: 1025px)

Comment: Thanks for finding the problem and the advice. Big help.

Comment: NP. Good Luck with the rest of the website.

Comment: Thanks. Take care